# Which one of these solutions has a better style/performance?

Tags: java, optimization

I found an interesting exercise on codingBat and now I have a Question About the Solution. The Task was:

> Given a string, return `true` if the first instance of `x` in the string is immediately followed by another `x`.

What I wrote is:

```
boolean doubleX(String str) {
      return str.contains("x") ? str.indexOf('x') == str.length() - 1 ? false : str.charAt(str.indexOf('x')) == str.charAt(str.indexOf('x') + 1) : false;
}
```

The solution they had on their page was:

```
boolean doubleX(String str) {
   int i = str.indexOf("x");
   if (i == -1) return false; // no "x" at all

   // Is char at i+1 also an "x"?
   if (i+1 >= str.length()) return false; // check i+1 in bounds?
      return str.substring(i+1, i+2).equals("x");
```

So now my Question is which solution has the better coding style? Which solution is more Beautiful or even more efficient?

Thanks for all answers

Comment: Imagine that you are another programmer that comes to read your solution. Everything is wrangled up on the one line return and it would take some extra time to absorb every condition and how they actually work together. Performance won't actually be of much difference if the compiler is a good one, because it will actually detect variables and encode the executables in a different way

Comment: 1) Better coding style: codingBat solution. Because easy to understand. 2) Beautiful: codingBat solution. Nice and clear 3) efficient: that depends.

Comment: How about str.indexOf("xx"); ? This is more readable and uses standard library code hence performant.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi doesn't work - it must be the first instance of `x` that is followed by an `x` - your solution would pick up any `xx`, even if there as single `x`s before then.

Comment: Regex is the tool for this job - these sorts of simple string pattern exercises are what Regex was desgined for.

Comment: What about `return str.indexOf("x") == str.indexOf("xx");`? Not as performant, but pretty clear.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi The Problem About your solution is that if one has a string like "hxhxx" the result would be true but the Task says return true if the first instance of "x" is followed by another "x".

Comment: @BoristheSpider: This is what java documentation says about indexOf method. "Returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified substring." And I've checked too and it always returns the first index of occurrence of xx string. E.g. String s = "saxxdxxaadxdfaxxxdsdsxx";
  System.out.println(s.indexOf("xx")); always returns 2. Check yourself and give me an example where it fails?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I don't think `return str.indexOf("x") == str.indexOf("xx");` would actually work. What if you were to have the following string `axyxx`?

Comment: @Mayhem it would because it's asked for the first instance of x to be followed by another x

Comment: @BoristheSpider: Oh ok, I got it what you meant :) It was exclusively for first occurence of x only. Sorry I misinterpreted.

Comment: Yep, sorry @BoristheSpider and onCC, my mistake, didn't properly read the question :(

Comment: Mayhem that's why computer languages have this nice feature called "comment".  So the reader doesn't have to decypher any code (whether in your preferred style or not) and can just read the terms of the contract explained in language a thousand times more natural than that of any other coder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably code it like this:

```
boolean doubleX(String str) 
{
    int index = str.indexOf("x");
    return (index >= 0 && index == str.indexOf("xx", index));
}
```

Probably not the most performant, but it handles every possibility.

*It can be slow if `indexOf("x")` and `indexOf("xx")` are far apart (unnecessary, long search for `"xx"`) or if both indices are very high (long search done twice).*

So another, slightly less intuitive, but more performant solution could be:

```
boolean doubleX(String str)
{
    int index = str.indexOf("x");
    return (index >= 0 && index < str.length() - 1 && str.charAt(index + 1) == 'x');
}
```

Comment: Note that `charAt` is `O(1)` - it's just an array access.

Comment: @Boris: `charAt()` may be O(1), but it may still be slow. Anyway, using `charAt()` you must first check if you are not beyond the end of the string, etc. Again, I guess my solition is not the most performant, but simply rather elegant. <g>

Comment: Indeed - the performance isn't really relevant, this is a two-pass solution. But I like it because it's very readable.

Comment: This code is readable but not efficient. Imagine a string of great length say finding the first x takes 5 minutes. Then second scanning for finding xx will take another horrible 5 minutes which won't be right. Instead when once found, it should just check for the next available character and should return the result instead of double scanning.

Comment: "Perhaps more performant" *definitely* so. Imagine the string "xaaaaaaaaaaa...(1 million things that are not xs)xx".

Comment: @Pushpesh: see my second solution. Only takes horrible 5 minutes, not 10 minutes.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Yes this is what exactly I posted too in my answer :)

Comment: @Andy: I agree. I took away the "perhaps". <g>

Comment: @Andy: I guess it depends on what I use it for. If I know my strings are never much longer than, say, 80 tokens, and the code is not time critical (most code of a program isn't, in my experience), I would use the simpler solution. For a general library, I would use the second one.